# Calculations of expected value and improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, statistics, expected-value

## set-up

$X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim \mathrm{\ i.i.d.\ } N(\theta, 1).$

The following holds.
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{n}}\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{\bar{X}}\right] = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{y}\exp{\left[-\frac{n}{2}(y-\theta)^2\right]}dy - \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{y}\exp{\left[-\frac{n}{2}(y-\theta)^2\right]}dy
$$

## Problem

We want to show that RHS first term tends to $\infty$ i.e. $\mathbb E[1/\bar{X}]$ doesn’t exist.

## What I know

For any $\epsilon > 0$, RHS first term is
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{y}\exp{\left[-\frac{n}{2}(y-\theta)^2\right]}dy \geq \int_0^\epsilon \frac{1}{y}\exp{\left[-\frac{n}{2}(y-\theta)^2\right]}dy.
$$

As $y \to 0$,
$$
\exp{\left[-\frac{n}{2}(y-\theta)^2\right]} \to \exp{\left[-\frac{n}{2}\theta^2 \right]} \overset{?}{>}\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{\ for\ all\ } \theta < \epsilon
$$
when $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small.

**Can you tell me why this inequality holds?**

Comment: $e^{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: In other words, is it that there is no deeper meaning to 1/2, but that we are evaluating a number that is somewhat smaller than 1?

Comment: @ytnb The $\frac12$ is just a scaling factor related to using the standard deviation and a normal density. It does not appear explicitly in the Gauss error function.  The important thing is that, for $y$ small enough, the number is larger than a positive constant before multiplying by $\frac1y$ and integrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Z\sim N(0,1)$ recall that $E(1/Z)$ does not exist. To see this, recall that $Z^2/2$ is gamma distributed and that for $s\geq -1/2$ we have $E((Z^2/2)^s)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+s)}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ which implies $$E(|Z|^{2s})=2^s\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+s)}{\sqrt{\pi}}.$$ Clearly $\lim_{s\to -1/2}E(|Z|^{2s})=E(1/|Z|)=\infty.$ The proof of $E(1/|Z+\theta|)=\infty$ is a little bit more difficult, based on the fact that $(Z+\theta)^2/2$ is a non central xi square distribution. Its Laplace transform is $L(s)=(s+1)^{-1/2}\exp\left(-s\theta^2/2(s+1)\right)$ which leads to the divergent integral$$E(1/|Z+\theta|)=\int_0^{\infty}L(s) s^{-1/2}\frac{ds}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$